# Remote query Windows Server 2008 for locked files

Tags: .net, windows-server-2008

Ok so I have a problem that is getting annoying: We have PDF files on a server that are regularly viewed by multiple users, but also have to be updated quite regularly by a single user. The user who does the edit sets the file as read only after editing but when other users open the file the server still locks it.

I can remote access the server and find out who is locking the file from Administrative tools -> Computer Management (Connect to another computer) -> System Tools -> Shared Folders -> Open Files.

The process of editing the PDF happens on an intranet site built on MVC, running on IIS so I would like to be able to tell the user who is editing the file who has the file locked so they can give them a call/IM and ask them to close it, and therefore stop bugging our admins all the time.

Im guessing this must be possible someone as the computer mgt interface manages it, but does anyone know how I can retrieve this list in .NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, openfiles.exe does it in command prompt.

Great example of how to implement it in .net here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/62357/Monitoring-Access-to-Your-Shared-Files-on-Network